# Azure App Service access only to other app service(s)

Tags: azure-appservice

I have 3 app services in Azure 2 Front end & 1 Web API. The front ens are public facing an when I started I kept the web API service as public as well and it worked pretty well. Now I want to restrict the Web API service only to my front ends.

I studied and understood(but could be wrong as I am completely new to Azure) that -

1. I need to create a Virtual Network in the same region as the App services - I created a Virtual Network
2. Enable Virtual Network Integration - I integrated 1 front end and the Web API - App Service to the VNET - default subnet
3. Enable Service Endpoint - Microsoft.Web in the VNet - Done

Now as I restrict networking of the Web API app service service to the My virtual Network/Subnet, My front end cannot access the API App Service any more

Answer (score 0):

**`Steps to Creating Azure App Services for Front-End and Web API Deployment`**

This might be a few additional steps or configurations you need to check to ensure your front-end apps can communicate with your Web API app securely within a Virtual Network

**Virtual Network (VNet) Integration:**

You've already integrated your front-end and Web API app services with the VNet, which is the first step. Make sure that both your front-end apps and the Web API app are integrated with the same VNet. This is crucial for internal communication

[image]

#### Service Endpoints

Enabling service endpoints for Microsoft.Web on your VNet is also correct. This action secures your network by ensuring that traffic from your VNet to Azure services remains on the Microsoft Azure backbone network. Double-check that the service endpoint is enabled on the subnet that is being used by your App Services

[image]

#### Network Security Group (NSG)

When you restrict your Web API app service to your virtual network/subnet, you need to ensure that there's a Network Security Group (NSG) associated with your subnet that explicitly allows traffic between your front-end App Services and your Web API App Service. Here's what you need to do:

- **Create or Update NSG Rules:** You need to create or update NSG rules to allow traffic from the front-end apps to the Web API app. Typically, you'd allow traffic over the ports that your Web API uses (e.g., HTTP/HTTPS 80/443) from the source of your front-end subnets to the destination of your Web API subnet.

[image]

#### Application Settings

**WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL:**
Ensure that the application setting `WEBSITE_VNET_ROUTE_ALL` is set to `1` for your App Services. This setting routes all outbound traffic from your App Service into your VNet, ensuring that calls to your Web API go through your VNet.

**Reference:**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-vnet-integration
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-web-sites-custom-domain
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-vnet-integration#troubleshoot-vnet-integration